# Create one observable from several tasks

Tags: system.reactive, rx-java

I want to create a method that accepts a `S` and returns an `Observable<T>` that is completed with one value after three (async) tasks are done.

The three tasks all run on Queues with their own consumers in separate threads.

Here's what I was thinking of:

- Task 1 receives `<S, Subject<T>>` via the queue and computes the value from `S` and sets in in the `Subject<T>` with `onNext` and then calls `onComplete()`.
- Task 2 and 3 receive an `<S, Subject<Void>>` and call `onComplete()` once they've done their job.

Task 1, 2 and 3 can run independently, and complete in random order.

Now I have three Subjects, One of `T`, and two of `Void`. I want to return the first one, but only let it emit the value `T` once *all* tasks are done. This is because I don't want any subscribers of the observable do anything with `T` until all tasks are completed.

What is the correct way to combine the Subjects to achieve this behavior? I can easily hack this together using `CountDownLatch` etc but was hoping there's a rx-native kind of way to tackle this.

And is my plan to use Subjects as callbacks via the queue the right approach? I used to use `CompletableFuture<T>` for this, but I want to migrate to RX.

Comment: Just as a quick rule of thumb - if you're using subjects in your design you're probably doing something wrong. You should always avoid subjects if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own `Subject` that does this for you but that's typically discouraged for a number of reasons. Instead you can also concatenate the three Observables/Subjects produced by your tasks. This operation produces an `Observable` which emits all values produced by these tasks, and only completes when all of the input Observables have completed.

Since their types slightly differ, you'll need to alter the signature of the Observables produced by the latter two tasks using `map()`.

```
Observable<T> output = Observable.concat(t1, 
    t2.map(in -> null).ignoreElements(), 
    t3.map(in -> null).ignoreElements());
```

If you want to wait for any subscribers to use the produced value until all Observables have completed, you can call the `last()` method on this `Observable`.

```
Observable<T> output = Observable.concat(t1, 
    t2.map(in -> null).ignoreElements(), 
    t3.map(in -> null).ignoreElements()).last();
```

Comment: This won't run the three tasks concurrently. You're going to get serialized calls. Also the `.last()` value will be `null` and never the desired value from `t1`.

Comment: The idea is that the three tasks emit values/completion through the Observables t1-t3. This won't run the three tasks, I'm assuming he's already taken care of that himself. This solution simply describes how to get the value when all tasks complete.

Indeed now a `null` will be emitted. I'll fix the solution.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP says that tasks 2 & 3 start when they get `S`. So, all three tasks must start concurrently when passed `S`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure where the subject is coming into play but you can synchronize the three Tasks by using `When` + `And` + `Then`

```
public IObservable<T> MyMethod<S, T>(S incoming) {

  //Create a new plan
  return Observable.When(

   //Start with Task one which will return an T from an S
   Observable.FromAsync(async () => await SomeTaskToTurnSIntoT(incoming))

   //Add in Task two which returns a System.Reactive.Unit
   .And(Observable.FromAsync(() => /*Do Task 2*/))

   //Same for Task 3
   .And(Observable.FromAsync(() => /*Do Task 3*/))

   //Only emit the item from the first Task.
   .Then((ret, _, __) => ret))

   //Finally we only want this to process once, then we will reuse the
   //existing value for subsequent subscribers
   .PublishLast().RefCount();
}
```

The above will wait until all three items are completed before it emits. One thing to note is that in Rx the `Void` object is really a `System.Reactive.Unit`, so you should be returning that if there is no value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Subject`s for this. Rather merge the observables using asynchronous schedulers. So you have:

```
T task1(S s);
void task2(S s);
void task3(S s);
```

Then

```
<S,T> Observable<T> get(S s) {
    return Observable.merge(
        Observable.just(s)
            .map(x -> task1(x))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
        (Observable<T>) Observable.just(s)
            .doOnNext(x -> task2(x))
            .ignoreElements()
            .cast(Object.class)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
        (Observable<T>) Observable.just(s)
            .doOnNext(x -> task3(x))
            .ignoreElements()
            .cast(Object.class)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
        // wait for completion before emitting the single value
        .last();
}
```

Comment: The reason I need Subjects (I think) is that the other task runs from a Queue, so it computes the result somewhere in the future and it needs to set the resulting value into something. So `task(x)` completes immediately because it just adds to the queue, but the result is set later on into the subject I pass onto the queue.

Comment: righto, didn't read it properly. The merge approach still works though. You just have to encapsulate the Subjects into the observables being merged. To be honest to go the whole hog with Rx on this I would just use schedulers for the queueing. Are you constrained in terms of your queue use?